# How many ng-model's can I add to the element?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model

```
 <td style="width:5%" class="active"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="rep.Selected"/></td>
```

Can I add more than one "ng-model" to the  element? Like that:

```
 <td style="width:5%" class="active"><input type="checkbox" ng-model="rep.Selected" ng-model="toDelete" /></td>
```

It will works?

Comment: You can only have one. If it 'works' I suspect it'll pick the last one.